# Tic Tac Toe Game Made In Python Win Conditions

Tags: python, random, tic-tac-toe

This is my first ever post on here, as usually I just follow tutorials on Youtube or whatever, but I really wanted to do a project mainly by myself. I made a little Tic Tac Toe game I was pretty proud of today in Python, but there is one thing that doesn't work. The win conditions. I put in the winLoseCondition() in different spots before, but it doesn't work. Once it gets to there, it either says I lose or win. I don't know how it decides before there is enough information. One other thing, sometimes the computer overwrites one of the places the player has gone, and I don't know why. I know I probably did 100 things wrong programming this and there is a way easier way of doing it, but there are many like it but this one is mine. So, the question I really am asking here is: How do I fix my code so that my win conditions, when fulfilled correctly, actually end the game at the correct time, and not at a random time when I place the function somewhere. Also, as a bonus, why is my computer/random O placing bot overwriting some of where the player places their X's? I know I could improve the thing that places the O's, but that is for another night.

```
import random
import sys
winCondition = False
def winLoseCondition():
    if board[1] and board[2] and board[3] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[1] and board[2] and board[3] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[1] and board[5] and board[9] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[1] and board[5] and board[9] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[3] and board[5] and board[7] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[3] and board[5] and board[7] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[1] and board[4] and board[7] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[1] and board[4] and board[7] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[2] and board[5] and board[8] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[2] and board[5] and board[8] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[3] and board[6] and board[9] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[3] and board[6] and board[9] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[4] and board[5] and board[6] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()
    if board[4] and board[5] and board[6] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[7] and board[8] and board[9] == 'X':
        print('You win!')
        sys.exit()
    if board[7] and board[8] and board[9] == 'O':
        print('You lose...')
        sys.exit()

while winCondition == False:
    board = {1: ' ',2: ' ',3: ' ',
                 4: ' ',5: ' ', 6: ' ',
                 7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '}
    print('We are going to play Tic Tac Toe')
    firstPlayerMove = input('What is your first move? (Input a number 1:9. 1 is the top left box. 9 is the bottom right box.)')
    #Player's First Move
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 1:
        board[1] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 2:
        board[2] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 3:
        board[3] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 4:
        board[4] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 5:
        board[5] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 6:
        board[6] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 7:
        board[7] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 8:
        board[8] = 'X'
    if int(firstPlayerMove) == 9:
        board[9] = 'X'
    #Computer's First Move:
    firstComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while firstComputerMove == int(firstPlayerMove):
        firstComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while firstComputerMove != int(firstPlayerMove):

        if firstComputerMove == 1:
            board[1] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 2:
            board[2] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 3:
            board[3] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 4:
            board[4] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 5:
            board[5] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 6:
            board[6] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 7:
            board[7] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 8:
            board[8] = 'O'
            break
        if firstComputerMove == 9:
            board[9] = 'O'
            break
    #Player's Second Move
    print('This is what the board looks like:')
    print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    secondPlayerMove = input('What is your second move? ')
    while int(secondPlayerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        secondPlayerMove = input('That space is already occupied. Please input a different number ')
    while int(secondPlayerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        secondPlayerMove = input('That space is already occupied. Please input a different number ')
    while int(secondPlayerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove:

        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'X'
            break
        if int(secondPlayerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'X'
            break
    #Computer's Second Move
    secondComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(secondComputerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        secondComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(secondComputerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        secondComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(secondComputerMove) == int(secondPlayerMove):
        secondComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(secondComputerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove or int(secondPlayerMove):

        if int(secondComputerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'O'
            break
        if int(secondComputerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'O'
            break
    #Player's Third Move
    print('This is what the board looks like:')
    print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    thirdPlayerMove = input('Please say where you want to move.')
    while int(thirdPlayerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        thirdPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(thirdPlayerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        thirdPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(thirdPlayerMove) == int(secondPlayerMove):
        thirdPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(thirdPlayerMove) == secondComputerMove:
        thirdPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(thirdPlayerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove or int(secondPlayerMove) or secondComputerMove:

        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'X'
            break
        if int(thirdPlayerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'X'
            break
    #Computer's Third Move
    thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) == int(secondPlayerMove):
        thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) == secondComputerMove:
        thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) == int(thirdPlayerMove):
        thirdComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(thirdComputerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove or int(secondPlayerMove) or secondComputerMove or int(thirdPlayerMove):

        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'O'
            break
        if int(thirdComputerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'O'
            break
    #Player's Fourth Move
    print('This is what the board looks like:')
    print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    fourthPlayerMove = input('Where do you want to move?')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == int(secondPlayerMove):
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == secondComputerMove:
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == int(thirdPlayerMove):
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) == thirdComputerMove:
        fourthPlayerMove = input('Sorry, that space is taken, please try again.')
    while int(fourthPlayerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove or int(secondPlayerMove) or secondComputerMove or int(thirdPlayerMove) or thirdComputerMove:

        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'X'
            break
        if int(fourthPlayerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'X'
            break
    #Computer's Fourth Move
    fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == int(firstPlayerMove):
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == firstComputerMove:
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == int(secondPlayerMove):
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == secondComputerMove:
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == int(thirdPlayerMove):
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == thirdComputerMove:
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) == int(fourthPlayerMove):
        fourthComputerMove = random.randint(1,9)
    while int(fourthComputerMove) != int(firstPlayerMove) or firstComputerMove or int(secondPlayerMove) or secondComputerMove or int(thirdPlayerMove) or thirdComputerMove or int(fourthPlayerMove):

        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 1:
            board[1] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 2:
            board[2] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 3:
            board[3] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 4:
            board[4] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 5:
            board[5] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 6:
            board[6] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 7:
            board[7] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 8:
            board[8] = 'O'
            break
        if int(fourthComputerMove) == 9:
            board[9] = 'O'
            break
    #Player's Last Move
    print('This is what the board looks like:')
    print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    print('There is only one last spot.')
    if board[1] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 1')
        board[1] = 'X'
    if board[2] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 2')
        board[2] = 'X'
    if board[3] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 3')
        board[3] == 'X'
    if board[4] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 4')
        board[4] = 'X'
    if board[5] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 5')
        board[5] = 'X'
    if board[6] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 6')
        board[6] = 'X'
    if board[7] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 7')
        board[7] = 'X'
    if board[8] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 8')
        board[8] = 'X'
    if board[9] == ' ':
        print('You had to move to spot 9')
        board[9] = 'X'
    #Final Board
    print('The final board looks like:')
    print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('_ _ _')
    print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    winCondition = True

print('The final board looks like:')
print(board[1] +  '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
print('_ _ _')
print(board[4] +  '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
print('_ _ _')
print(board[7] +  '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
```

Comment: A little hint: can you think of a more efficient way of checking whether or not spaces are already occupied than checking a move against all previous moves? Remember that you already have an internal representation of the board (in the `board` list)

Comment: You cant do `if board[1] and board[2] and board[3] == 'X':` While it does sound logical that it would check the 3 variables if its equal X , what it really does is to check if board[1] is True(True if the value is not 0), if board[2] is True, and if board[3] == X. your condition should look like this    `if board[1] == 'X' and board[2] == 'X' and board[3] == 'X':`

Comment: For the second mistake , im missing some code but from what i can see you check if the Move the computer chose is equal to the Move of the player, you should instead check if the array board contains a letter of if its empty. Also some tip i can give : you should replace all the `if int(firstPlayerMove) == 1 to 9:   board [1to 9] = 'x'` by  a single` board[int(firstPlayerMove)] = x` this would reduce your code length by a lot (you can do the same with the computer)